# Any ideas about the energy feel I constantly have?

Tags: personal-practice, beginner

I'm going to try to describe this, but I'm honestly not sure how to. I have this vibration feeling just under my skin what seems like all the time. It's like a feeling of energy but it feels like it's vibrating. Oddly, if I get awoken abruptly, I actually feel the energy go CRAZY to the point my whole body shakes. Sorry in advance if this sounds crazy, as I really don't know the best way to describe it.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you relate that to Buddhism? I would like to help you with an answer, but I can see no connection.

Comment: Maybe you should see a medical doctor, probably a neurologist.

Comment: maybe a really intense experience of continuity or affective obstruction. not to validate your experience as being meaningfully buddhist, it could just be a psychological problem

Comment: I think it is an interesting experience and you may try to ask different people about it, but be sober accepting their answers. *My personal* experience suggests, if you feel good *and* you are advanced then it is OK. If you don’t feel good, that maybe you have to do something with that.

Comment: Allison, can you please clarify if you are asking about an experience that occurs during meditation or  "all the time"? That will help determine whether this is on topic for this site or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Sabbo pajjalito loko, sabbo loko pakampito.*

The entire universe is nothing but combustion and vibration.

When meditating and you mind gets sensitive you will start feeling the vibration in your body. Also when meditating when old formation dissolve this creates different experiences including vibrations.